# Insert an Object into an Array using Literal Notation in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm parsing a document that has a known repeating structure. There is a heading (1 line), a sub-heading(1 line), and a content area (unknown # of lines).
The format for each item in the document is shown below:

```
 
=========================
       Head Text
=========================
      SubHead Text
=========================
 Content Text Line 1
 Content Text Line 2
 ...
 Content Text Line 8
```

I want to create an Array that contains an Object for each section.
Something like:

```
 var item = [];

 items[0] = {
     head: "head1 text",
     subHead: "subHead1 text",
     content: "content1 text"};
 items[1] = {
     head: "head2 text",
     subHead: "subHead2 text",
     content: "content2 text"};
```

I am having trouble efficiently traversing the document and dynamically adding each Object into the Array. I get an error under section 2 telling me that "page is null or not an object".

```
 var count = 0;
 while( !stream.AtEndOfStream ){
 page[count] = stream.ReadLine();
 count++;
 }

var item = [{}];

var section = 0;

var i = 0, k = 0;
while (i < page.length) {
    if (~page[i].indexOf("=====")) {
        if(section == 0) {
            item[k].head = page[i+1];
            section++;
        } else      
        if (section == 1) {
            item[k].subHead1 = page[i+1];   
            section++;
            i++;
        } else
        if (section == 2) {
            var j = i+1;
            while(!~page[j].indexOf("=====")) {
                item[k].content += page[j] + "\n";
                j++;
            }   
                section = 0;
                k++;
        }       
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: `page` isn't declared in your code sample.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that "page" is an array of strings, ala page[0] = "a string";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
var item = [{}];
```

to this:

```
var item = [];
```

Next, change this:

```
if (~page[i].indexOf("=====")) {
```

to this:

```
if (~page[i].indexOf("=====")) { 
    item[k] = {};
```

I am not sure if that will work, but the basic idea is to create a blank array (var item = [];) and then add objects when needed (item[k] = {}). Previously you were trying to add properties to undefined objects.

Answer (score 0):

`page` is null because it has not been declared, in your snippet at least.

Comment: I should have included that part of the code. page is a simple array of strings...

Comment: You may have a scoping issue with `page`. Try `var page=[];` at the very top of your script to see if it scopes globally.